# How to write MappedByteBuffer to socket outputstream (server to client) with no copy

Tags: java, nio, java-io, virtual-memory, memory-mapped-files

In Java code, I have a region of file mapped using MappedByteBuffer and I need to send this to the client (write to Outputstream). I need to make sure that while sending/writing to socket, it does not create any copy due to memory constraints. How can I achieve this? Will Bytebuffer.array() serve this purpose?

Sharing the code. Note: FileChannel is read-only and I need to send ByteBuffer data as it is.

```
private void writeData(Socket clientSocket, MappedByteBuffer byteBuffer){
    Path path = Paths.get(myfile);
    MappedByteBuffer memoryMappedBuffer = null;
        try (FileChannel fChannel = FileChannel.open(path, StandardOpenOption.READ)) {
            memoryMappedBuffer = fChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, location, size);
        }catch(){
        
    //How can i write memoryMappedBuffer to socket outputStream without copying data...? like
    clientSocket.getOutputStream().write(memoryMappedBuffer .array());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are creating the socket yourself, you can use [`SocketChannel.open()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html#open(java.net.SocketAddress)) instead, and use [`write(ByteBuffer)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/WritableByteChannel.html#write(java.nio.ByteBuffer)). It manages the socket internally.

```
InetSocketAddress address = ...
SocketChannel channel = SocketChannel.open(address);
channel.write(memoryMappedBuffer);
// ...
channel.close(); // Closes the connection
```

If you have a pre-existing socket, you can create a `Channel` from the socket's output stream. However this allocates a (reused) temporary buffer.

```
WritableByteChannel channel = Channels.newChannel(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
channel.write(memoryMappedBuffer);
// ...
channel.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description you want to write to a socket the content of a file, or a slice of the file, slice that it is mapped to the virtual address space of your java process.

The memory-mapped files is used in general to share memory between multiple processes or to minimize the I/O operations on disk when your process is writing and reading data to/from the same files (a concrete example is Kafka which uses this procedure).

In your case, when you write the data to a socket, that socket has a buffer (regardless if it's blocking or non-blocking). When the buffer is full you will not be able to write, until the receiver acknowledge the data, and the buffer is cleared. Now, if the receiver is slow, you will remain with that portion of the file loaded to your main memory for a long time which can affect the performance of your server (I suppose you will not have a single consumer/client for your server).

One good and efficient solution is to use **pipe streaming** which sends data from your server to a consumer (in this case a socket) in a producer/consumer way. By default the PipeInputStream uses a buffer of 1024 bytes (you can increase it), meaning that only 1024 bytes will be kept in the memory at one moment in time for a specific execution thread. If your process has 500 clients, then you will consume only 500*1024 bytes = 512Kb. If one reader is slow, then that producer will be slow also without putting pressure on your process memory.

If all you have to do is to write the content of various files to sockets, I don't know how using memory-mapped files can helps you.